# Boxed environment for with title and alignment

Tags: boxes, framed

I would want to achieve something similar than these nice descriptive boxed styles used to describe problems in *Combinatorial Optimization: Theory and Algorithms* by Jens Vygen et al.

[image]

The box has the length of `\textwidth`. I have found out that fancybox can do something similar, but I haven't been able to add the title correctly or align the text into two sections. Is there a good package for achieving something similar?

Comment: Packages `mdframed`, `tcolorbox` .... or a 'primitive' tabular environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quite primitive version with `tabularx`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\myboxstuff}[3]{%
  \noindent%
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|llX|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|X|}{\scshape #1} \tabularnewline
    & & \tabularnewline
    \textit{Instance:} & & #2 \tabularnewline
    & & \tabularnewline
    \textit{Task:} & & #3 \tabularnewline
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}%
}

\begin{document}

\myboxstuff{Linear Programming}{Some Matrix\dots}{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @ChristianHupfer , I added little padding between the top line and bottom line and between rows and then it was perfect!

Comment: @Allstar: Well, of course, that's your free decision of style

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions, in two variants: one also based on `tabularx`, the other based on `framed` and `enumitem` defines a `programdescr` environment which can break across pages. Two commands are defined: `\instance` and `task`.

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} \usepackage{MinionPro}
    \usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
    \setcellgapes{4pt}
    \usepackage{enumitem, framed}
\usepackage{etoolbox, xcolor} %


\newenvironment{programdescr}[1][]{\FrameSep=6pt\framed%
\setlist[description, 1]{font=\normalfont\itshape, , wide = 0pt, labelwidth=1.6cm, leftmargin=\labelwidth, itemindent=0pt, style=sameline}%
\newcommand\instance{\item[Instance:]}\newcommand\task{\item[Task:]}%
\noindent\textsc{#1}\vspace{-0.5\topsep}\description}%
{\enddescription\vspace{-\topsep}\endframed}%

    \begin{document}

    \makegapedcells
    \noindent \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\itshape}p{1.2cm} >{\arraybackslash}X |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|>{\scshape}l|}{Linear Programming} \\ Instance: & A matrix $ A \in \mathbf R^{m \times n} $ and column vectors $ b \in \mathbf R^m $, $ c \in \mathbf R^n$. \\%
    Task: & Find a column vector $ b \in \mathbf R^n $ such that $ Ax \le b $ and $ c^\top x $ is maximum, decide that $ \{x \in \mathbf R^n\:\colon\: Ax \le b \} $ is empty, or decide that for all $ \alpha  \in \mathbf R $ there is an $ x \in \mathbf R^n$ with $ Ax \le b$ and $ c^\top x > \alpha $. \\%
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \vskip1cm
    \noindent \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\itshape\raggedleft}p{1.2cm}>{\arraybackslash}X |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|>{\scshape}l|}{Linear Programming} \\ Instance: & A matrix $ A \in \mathbf R^{m \times n} $ and column vectors $ b \in \mathbf R^m $, $ c \in \mathbf R^n$. \\%
    Task: & Find a column vector $ b \in \mathbf R^n $ such that $ Ax \le b $ and $ c^\top x $ is maximum, decide that $ \{x \in \mathbf R^n\:\colon\: Ax \le b \} $ is empty, or decide that for all $ \alpha  \in \mathbf R $ there is an $ x \in \mathbf R^n$ with $ Ax \le b$ and $ c^\top x > \alpha $. \\%
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}

    \FrameSep=6pt\begin{framed}
    \noindent\textsc{Linear Programming}\vspace{-0.5\topsep}
      \begin{description}[font=\normalfont\itshape, labelwidth=1.6cm, leftmargin=\labelwidth, itemindent=0pt, align=right]

     \item[Instance:]
     A matrix $ A \in \mathbf R^{m \times n} $ and column vectors $ b \in \mathbf R^m $, $ c \in \mathbf R^n$.

    \item[Task: ] Find a column vector $ b \in \mathbf R^n $ such that $ Ax \le b $ and $ c^\top x $ is maximum, decide that $ \{x \in \mathbf R^n\:\colon\: Ax \le b \} $ is empty, or decide that for all $ \alpha  \in \mathbf R $ there is an $ x \in \mathbf R^n$ with $ Ax \le b$ and $ c^\top x > \alpha $.

        \end{description}
    \vspace{-\topsep}
    \end{framed}

    \begin{programdescr}[Linear Programming]
    \instance
     A matrix $ A \in \mathbf R^{m \times n} $ and column vectors $ b \in \mathbf R^m $, $ c \in \mathbf R^n$.

    \task Find a column vector $ b \in \mathbf R^n $ such that $ Ax \le b $ and $ c^\top x $ is maximum, decide that $ \{x \in \mathbf R^n\:\colon\: Ax \le b \} $ is empty, or decide that for all $ \alpha  \in \mathbf R $ there is an $ x \in \mathbf R^n$ with $ Ax \le b$ and $ c^\top x > \alpha $.

    \end{programdescr}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is also good solution. Though, I could not replicate your results. For some reason the programdesc doesn't align the the two items horizontally correctly: [see link](http://imgur.com/a/xLlSQ)

Comment: The labelwidth parameter was not sufficient my font apparantly

Comment: Well, just change its value. I used Minion Pro in size 11pt, just because I  like this font. For the problem of alignment, could you post a minimal working example that shows what happens?

Comment: all is well. The problem was that I was not considering that font size could affect the results. I used Adobe Utopia 12pt and it caused the problems. I just increased the labelwidth parameter to correct the problem as you suggested.